# Is this a bug with the asp net core ActionLink Html helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, actionlink, tag-helpers

I am writing a new Razor Pages application (this is my first time with Razor pages rather than MVC), and I came to the point where I was needing to create a link and for the life of me I could not figure out why it was not working even though I tried every single variation of the parameters to the ActionLink method that I could think of.  I then instead used the Anchor Tag Helper methodology instead with the exact smae parameters and it worked beautifully.
I was already confused when I scaffolded my views because the code generation uses both the Tag Helpers and the Html Helpers where as my brain tells me you should really pick one or the other and try to be as consistent as possible.

The code in the cshtml file is as follows:

```
<a asp-page="./DeleteIngredient" asp-route-MenuItemId="@item.MenuItemId" asp-route-IngredientId="@item.IngredientId">Delete</a>

@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteIngredient", new { MenuItemId = @item.MenuItemId, IngredientId = @item.IngredientId })
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "./DeleteIngredient", new { MenuItemId = @item.MenuItemId, IngredientId = @item.IngredientId })
```

The Tag Helper correctly generates the following url:

https://localhost:44308/MenuItems/DeleteIngredient?MenuItemId=c469f993-9cac-4adc-bf63-2aba9be249c9&IngredientId=2f2863b1-27f4-4c62-93d6-84f27acb98fd

The Html Helpers generate the following:

https://localhost:44308/MenuItems/Details/c469f993-9cac-4adc-bf63-2aba9be249c9?MenuItemId=c469f993-9cac-4adc-bf63-2aba9be249c9&IngredientId=2f2863b1-27f4-4c62-93d6-84f27acb98fd&action=DeleteIngredient

Note: the links are on a page with the URL:
https://localhost:44308/MenuItems/Details/c469f993-9cac-4adc-bf63-2aba9be249c9

In summary, am I doing something wrong? Or does this appear to be a bug in the asp net core Html.ActionLink method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` is for MVC pattern, it requires Action and Controller names. Since you are using razor pages it will not work because you don't have controllers and action but you have Pages! So, your first approach is correct.

As an alternative you may use `Url.Page` to generate the link as below:

```cs
<a href="@(Url.Page("./DeleteIngredient", null, new { MenuItemId = item.MenuItemId, IngredientId = item.IngredientId })">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Laz, I found this link which verifies what you are saying:
https://forums.asp.net/t/2140274.aspx?Razor+Page+Navigation

I verified too that none of the scaffoled code uses the ActionLink helper.  I come from an MVC background and have used it in the past, what really threw me off is that the scaffolded code uses the HTML helpers for some things and the Tag Helpers for others.  For example the Create page that is scaffolded uses "<input asp-for=" where as the details page uses the Html Helpers such as "@Html.DisplayFor".  But perhaps that is better as a new question. Thanks!

Comment: For any future curious people, I posted the other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825275/why-does-razor-pages-scaffolding-use-html-helpers-and-not-tag-helpers-for-inde