# Why does Razor Pages scaffolding use HTML Helpers (and not Tag Helpers) for Index, Details and Delete pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, html-helper, razor-pages, scaffolding, tag-helpers

I recently started my first project using Razor Pages, I am using EF Core and have scaffolded all of my models into CRUD Razor Pages.  Something I noticed was that the Create and Edit Razor Pages that are generated use Tag Helpers to display the data. i.e.

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ViewModel.Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ViewModel.Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Whereas the Index, Details, and Delete Pages use Html Helpers to display the data. i.e.

```
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ViewModel.Name)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ViewModel.Name)
    </dd>
```

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2) from Microsoft says that "Tag Helpers reduce the explicit transitions between HTML and C# in Razor views. In many cases, HTML Helpers provide an alternative approach to a specific Tag Helper, but it's important to recognize that Tag Helpers don't replace HTML Helpers and there's not a Tag Helper for each HTML Helper.".

But certainly these basic display fields could be displayed with Tag Helpers.  This seems to me like a rather frivolous inconsistency and I would think that it would be better practice to use Tag Helpers primarily and Html Helpers only when absolutely neccecary.

I assume that the developers had a reason for doing it this way, but what that might be escapes me.  Could anyone please shine some light on this for me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: there's no tag helpers for display.

Expanded:

Having tag helpers for things like inputs makes sense: there's specific HTML tags associated with that. Things get a lot more blurry with display. Each individual developer might want to use different tags for display: `span`, `strong`, `th`, `dt`, etc. There's no one-size fits all here. You might not even want a tag at all. By default `Html.DisplayFor` and `Html.DisplayNameFor` just output the values, without any tags.

Also, these are templated helpers, which means you as a developer can actually add templates to `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates` and customize how things are displayed. For example, you could at a `String.cshtml` view there, with something like:

```
@model string
<strong>@Model</strong>
```

And now, any string property displayed using `Html.DisplayFor` would be wrapped in `strong` tags. This level of customization wouldn't be possible with tag helpers.

**EDIT**

FWIW, if you really want to use tag helpers, you can just add your own. For example:

```
public class DisplayNameTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "strong";
        output.Content.SetContent(For.Metadata.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<display-name for="MyProperty" />
```

Writing a `DisplayTagHelper` would be similar in concept, but a bit more difficult. You can get the value from `For.Model`. However, this is typed as `object`. Using information available on `For.Metadata`, you'd need to determine what you're actually working with and probably have a few different branches to display things differently depending on the type. There's also `For.Metadata.DataFormatString` that would need to be taken into account with things like decimals, DateTimes, etc.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense I suppose, but wouldnt the top example with the label and span in my question be considered Tag Helpers for non-input fields?

Comment: I was just giving an example with `input`. In the case of a label, the HTML element is obviously going to be `label`. In the case of validation, they did basically just arbitrarily decide that the element was going to be a `span`, but something had to be picked, and `span` makes sense. I suppose you could argue that they should have made tag helpers for display that just used `span`, but I think that's actually more objectionable. While the validation needs some sort of wrapper element regardless, display doesn't. Purists wouldn't like the imposition of extraneous tags.